# Hash session login sometimes works, sometimes doesn't

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies

I am stuck here. I made a very simple login script based on sessions and cookies. It's nothing fancy.

What i have is this:

On top of the page: `<?php session_start(); ?>`
After a succesfull registration, somewhere around line 400:

On page 1, after a succesfull registration, sessions are set.

```
<?php    
    $hash = md5(time()); // Time is just for testing purposes.
    $_SESSION['emailadres'] = filter_var($emailadres, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $_SESSION['hash'] = $hash;
?>
```

The login and emailadres are succesfully stored within the database, then the page get's forwarded: `<?php header("location: nextpage.php"); ?>`

The next page requires a successfull registration and session login:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0);
session_start();
$emailadres = filter_var($_SESSION["emailadres"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$hash = filter_var($_SESSION["hash"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

That's it.

It goes right about 75% of the times, but sometimes, following the exact same road, the hash in the database and the hash in the session are not the same.

Anyone a suggestion? Has it perhaps something to do with P3P and such. See:
[iFrames Iexplorer doesn't write or read sessions (or cookies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438461/iframes-iexplorer-doesnt-write-or-read-sessions-or-cookies/14439820#14439820)

Comment: I see that $hash is generated by script not user, once you saved in $_SESSION['hash'] why you need to validate, and see you used FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL in page 1 and in page 2 you used FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING why?

Comment: Typo's the first hash isn't filtered, the session is.

Comment: even thi $hash = filter_var($_SESSION["hash"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); not required on nextpage.php

Comment: I deleted it and i appreciate your help, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: why not just creating $hash on nextpage.php?

Comment: Because the next page is only allowed when the registration on the previous page was succesfull.

Comment: ok then do not create $hash unless reg was successful!

Comment: The problem is that hash is the check to see if the registration was succesfull. The combination is stored in the database and fetched to see if it was succesfull. Then the hash and the emailadres in the sessions are used to see if the right person is logged in.

Comment: Is it possible that it has anything to do with P3P. The page SOMETIMES is opened in an iFrame. However, errors also occur when it's opened on the same site. I really don't get it anymore. I am using a fallback with cookies, but those fail in iframes (in IE)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438461/iframes-iexplorer-doesnt-write-or-read-sessions-or-cookies/14439820#14439820